# Why parseInt 0.11 is not NaN but 0?

Tags: javascript, parsing

Is this normal?

```
newItemRowNumber
'0.11'
parseInt(newItemRowNumber)
0
```

I would expect that it is not parseable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

`0` is a numerial.

`.` is not.

So it takes the `0`, ignores the `.`, ignores everything after the `.`, and you get `0`.

Answer (score 3):

parseInt parses the string for real numbers 0-9 at the start of the string. When it encounters a non integer character it stops parsing, in this case the .

19aaa becomes 19
0.11 becomes 0
11.111 becomes 11
abc11 becomes NaN
0xDEAD becomes 57005(Because of hexadecimal numbers)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal because parseInt will just cut the fraction part from the given number string. And return the int value of the left side number of the dot.
Here is Link [parseInt() in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description).

As you are parsing float its better you can use parseFloat()

```
console.log(parseFloat("0.11"))
>>0.11
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).